# When shall "row" be use in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I came accros [this site](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works) explaining the functioning of Bootstrap and their grid layout.

Their explaining that you should use a `row` in a `container` and a `col-...` in a `row` but what I dont know and dont especially get is : Should I use two `row` in the same `container` if the col-... are managing their selves ?

I explicite : You have this ↓

```
<div class="container"> <!-- First Case -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container"> <!-- Second Case -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is completely different still; it is rendering the same exact way..

You can see the result there : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10736/)

So : **Which way shall I prefer/use ?** and **Is there a difference ?**

Comment: Have a look: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: `.row` elements clear any floats for one. Take a look at your fiddle when one column has a bigger height than the others: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10737/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to understand that `.row` **clears the floating columns inside**, which you want in case you don't have full control of the height of your contained columns.

See this updated fiddle of yours to understand why the second example you gave is the cleaner way:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10739/

Edit: It has to be noted that using an additional row has a harsh drawback: You can no longer decide you want to see more columns next to each other in higher resolutions.

Comment: Ok so correct me If I'm wrong : Eventually I could use the first case (single `row`) if I want to do some smart and well think positioning but its tricky **and** I should prefer the second way if I want something clean ?

Answer (score 0):

Row class can help you when you do not want make your elements free- flow in your container. Row controls the elements under it and make them keep flowing under the row container. Its a separation for elemets

Find this updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10736/) of yours.

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">
        <!-- free flow under this row -->
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```